# Recurrence relation T(n)=nT(n/2)+n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How to solve the recurrence relation $$T(n)=nT(n/2)+n$$
with initial condition $$T(1)=1$$

I tried to let
$$ U(k) = 2^k U(k-1) + 2^k$$
and then $T(n) = U(log(n))$

However, this approach did not yield meaningful results, as I encountered difficulty in solving $U$
due to the presence of a constant term $2^k$.

.

Comment: Сonsider $n$ as a power of two and try to substitute recursively - state in the question what you get.

Comment: Try to continue following: let $n=2^k$, then $T(2^k)=2^k\cdot T(2^{k-1})+2^k = 2^{2k-1}\cdot T(2^{k-2})+2^{2k-1}+2^k=\cdots$ at last you'll have $T(1)$ and then need to find formula for sum and power.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this approach and arrived at the expression 
$2^{(k^2 + k)/2} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{ik-(i^2 - i)/2}$
 . Am I right? If so, how can I express the time complexity of this sum in terms of Big O notation

Comment: Return back to $n$ as $k=\log_2 n$. And, before, does last sum looks like sum of geometrical progression?

Comment: Yes, I agree (I ran it in Python, and the results are the same). However, how can I simplify it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate your result and here answer the question as to simplifying the result, in particular, the exponents.

From your result in one of the comments

$$
T(k)=2^{(k^2 + k)/2} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^{ik-(i^2 - i)/2}
$$

The first exponent can be expressed as $(k^2 + k)/2=\text{binomial}(k+1,2)$. The second required searching in OEIS, entry A141419 ([OEIS A141419](https://oeis.org/A141419)). This is identified as a triangle read by rows, that is,

$$
ik-(i^2 - i)/2=\text{binomial}(k+1,2)-\text{binomial}(k+1-i,2)
$$

With both $k$ and $i$ being vectors, the exponents itself becomes a triangle matrix. The first nine rows are shown below.

$$
\begin{align}
&1\\
&2\quad  3\\
&3\quad  5\quad  6\\
&4\quad   7\quad   9\quad 10\\
&5\quad   9\quad  12\quad  14\quad  15\\
&6\quad  11\quad  15\quad  18\quad  20\quad  21\\
&7\quad  13\quad  18\quad  22\quad  25\quad  27\quad  28\\
&8\quad  15\quad  21\quad  26\quad  30\quad 33\quad 35\quad 36\\
&9\quad 17\quad 24\quad 30\quad 35\quad 39\quad 42\quad 44\quad  45\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I considered sum
$$S_n=2^{1}+2^{1+2}+2^{1+2+3}+\cdots+2^{1+2+3+\cdots+n}=(\sqrt{2})^{1\cdot 2}+(\sqrt{2})^{2\cdot 3}+(\sqrt{2})^{3\cdot 4}+\cdots+(\sqrt{2})^{n\cdot (n+1)}=\\
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(\sqrt{2})^{k\cdot (k+1)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}u_k\quad(1)$$
which is sum of, possibly, it can be called "quasi-geometric" progression members, because recurrence connection is $u_{k+1}=2^{k+1}\cdot u_k$ i.e. we have variable ratio.

Very rough estimation for sum gives
$$S_n=O\Big(n \cdot (\sqrt{2})^{n\cdot (n+1)}\Big)\quad(2)$$.

I keep trying to simplify $(1)$ (as much as the NY allows), though, imo,   [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) gives me hope, that $(2)$ is tight. I would be grateful to anyone who has already seen something similar and can shed more light than I can now.